# alert not being fired when I append a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery

On this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/zyUkd/46/ the divs 'Hello 01' & 'Hello 02' fire an alert when they are clicked. When i click 'Add New' a new div is added but when I click on this div the alert is not fired even though it is styled with same css .

How can I amend this so that the alert is fired when a new div is appended ?

Code from jsFiddle for posterity

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".myDivs").click(function() {
         alert('Clicked');
    });

    $("#button").click(get);   
    function get() {
        $(".connected").append("<div class=\"myDivs\">hello</div>");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="connected">
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 01</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 02</div>
</div>
<input name="Button3" type="button" value="Add New" id="button">
```

​
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need delegate event handler, because your way on bind event only bind event to existing DOM `.myDivs`, but not for upcoming.

```
$(".connected").on('click', '.myDivs', function() {
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/zyUkd/47/)**

For more detail go **[here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Answer (score 0):

That's because your jQuery is using the `document.ready` to make the assignment. Because this element was not present at the load, it does not have this assignment. You need to make this assignment separately.

Comment: it's okay to put this in docready. he just needs to make sure he uses the appropriate jQuery method (which in this case is `.on(...)`

Answer (score 0):

the answer thecodeparadox gave is valid. But I went ahead and updated your fiddle to fully match the latest jQuery convention.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GWg8w/1/)

Here's a link to the jQuery documentation for more information:
[jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)